# Why DCs are missing from DFS tab on GPOs folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Our DCs are all Win2008R2.

From any Win2008R2 server in domain, if I go to GPO center store, all the DCs are listed on DFS tab, so I can switch in between.

But from any Win2012R2 server in domain, There is only one DC listed on DFS tab.

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Anyone has any idea please?